# calculate average number an array (asssembly)

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

```
data segment
  a db 0,3,5,7,5 
  average db ?
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:    
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax

mov ax,0
mov bl,5
mov cx,5
lea si,a

dong:
add ax,[si]
inc si
dec cx
cmp cx,0
jne dong
jmp bak

bak:    
div bl           ;ax/5=al
mov average,al
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h  
ends

end start
```

I can not calculate the average...What is missing in my codes

Comment: If you will step in emu8086's debugger over instruction, after first `add ax,[si]` the `ax` should contain value 0300h (768). Then at `div bl` when you are calculating average from the big total sum, it will cause division error. Try it yourself?

Comment: ı tried but no changed...

Comment: Yes, it's deterministic. Every time you will try to debug it, you should get into `ax` value `0300h` after first `add ax,[si]` and division error from `div bl` at the end of sum. (I didn't ask you to change anything, I asked you to try in debugger, that it works exactly as you wrote the code). Also from the question is not clear, what you want to achieve. You don't comment on data types, on algorithm used, etc... surely one can guess a lot from the way the source is written, but I'm not in guessing mood today. For a start you should define valid ranges for values and sum (and average).

Comment: Once you know, what values you want to support, you can decide on correct data types (byte? word? 32 bit integers? arbitrary integers? floats?). Then you can correct array definition with picked data type. Then you can correct code to work with picked data type. At this moment you define array as BYTES (`db`), but access it as WORDS (`add AX,`), which makes the first `add` produce value `300h` instead of expected (?) `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> a db 0,3,5,7,5
> ```

With an array that is defined to contain **byte** values, you need to also read these values **as bytes**! The instruction `add ax,[si]` is reading these values **as words**. That's clearly wrong.

There're a few solutions here:

- Do a cascade a byte-sized additions

  ```
  add al, [si]  ;Add 1 byte-sized array element to AL
  adc ah, 0     ;Takes care of a potential carry from previous addition
  ```
- Read the byte value in the low part of a pre-zeroed word register, then do a word-sized addition

  ```
  mov dl, [si]  ;Read 1 byte-sized array element in DL, DH was zeroed beforehand!
  add ax, dx    ;Add to result in AX
  ```

---

The rest of your program is OK, but it can be improved a bit.

> ```
> mov ax,0
> ```

Clearing a register is better done via XOR-ing the register with itself. So here it becomes `xor ax, ax`.

> ```
> dec cx
> cmp cx,0
> jne dong
> ```

Because the `dec cx` instruction already sets the flags including the zero flag (ZF) that you want, there's no need to use `cmp cx,0` before looping back.

> ```
> jmp bak
>
> bak:
> ```

This `jmp bak` is useless since the code can just as easily fall through.

---

Applying the above gives:

```
 xor ax, ax    ;Set AX=0
 mov cx, 5
 lea si, a
dong:
 add al, [si]  ;Add 1 byte-sized array element to AL
 adc ah, 0     ;Takes care of a potential carry from previous addition
 inc si
 dec cx
 jnz dong
 mov cl, 5
 div cl        ;AX/5 -> AL
 mov average, al
```

Note that I avoided using `BL` simply by re-using `CL`.